# Searching styles for indoor maps

Tags: style, references, mapping, indoor

I have data that represents Airport floor plans stored in GeoJSON format.

Are there any standards, guidance, or good practices for Indoor Maps Styling?
Any references or resources would be useful.

Comment: What are your requirements/demands/implementation scope to those indoor mapping styles? Or your question is just "in general"? Be careful with it otherwise, it can be labelled as too broad.

Comment: My data is in geojson format represents Airport floor plans.